# Vim and terminator programming environment

Tags: vim, development-environment, terminator

Creating a programming environment using vim and terminator.
I would like to achieve something close to the picture below.

Yesterday, I found a website with an interesting solution on it, for an environment using terminator and vim, but I'm not sure how to achieve it.
Terminator can split screens and resize, etc.. but in the picture it looks like there's only 2 terminal screens (highlighted with red an grey) even though there are 5 panels.

The website I found the solution on: http://www.igordejanovic.net/2015/10/21/terminator-and-vim-love.html

Picture:
[image: environment]

I would like to achieve something like this, but I have no idea what those 2 panels on the sides are.

Would like to be able to see 3 or 4 panels, one is a file exlorer like thing (left in the picture) a vim panel, and a compiler / tools panel. Optionally a function list like there's one in the picture on the right.
Any idea what those panels are, and how are 3 different things in apparently 1 terminal screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The left and right are [NerdTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) and [Tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) plugins I believe. But before you install these (or any other) plugins try to see what Vim offers out of the box and if you *really* require these plugins for your workflow. For file explorer and tags, see `:h netrw` and `:h tags`.

Comment: @Harish has the right answer. Vim offers a lot more than most people tend to realize, and the biggest mistake beginners make is grabbing every shiny plugin and tool that every Tom, Dick and Harry suggest on their blogs in an attempt to make vim work exactly like another IDE that the user is familiar with. This is not Vim's strongpoint, Vim is strong precisely because it is not like most IDEs.

That being said, if you're going to use vim plugins (because many are so very handy), first look into getting yourself a plugin manager, such as pathogen or vundle.